# Explain why the projection of a point in a plane is a linear transformation.

Tags: transformation

Given the plane (1) x+2y+3z=0 in ${{R}^{3}}$
And a point $M({{x}_{0}},{{y}_{0}},{{z}_{0}})$in ${{R}^{3}}$not in the plane (1).
Find the projection of the point M onto the plane (1)
And explain why the orthogonal projection of a point in a plane  is a linear transformation.

I found the Parametric equations of the line that passes through point and its projection .Why this is a linear transformation?

$\begin{align}
  & {{x}_{0}}^{\prime }={{x}_{0}}+t \\ 
 & {{y}_{0}}^{\prime }={{y}_{0}}+2t \\ 
 & {{z}_{0}}^{\prime }={{z}_{0}}+3t \\ 
\end{align}$

Comment: There are plenty of projections. Which projection do you talk about ? orthogonal projection w.r.t. the euclidian scalar product ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the parametric equation you have found?